# Constant char keeps on casting to int

Tags: c++, c++builder

Stackoverflow users!
I am using Borland C++ Builder 6 for creating my program. Yes, I know that it is outdated for last two millon years, however, I **have** to use this IDE. I have a String which I need to split. So I use the following method:

```
void Orders::split(TStringList* lout, char* str, const char* separator) {
  for(char* tok = strtok(str, separator); tok!=NULL; tok = strtok(NULL, separator))
      lout->Add(tok);
}
```

Also, I have a separator defined as a preprocessor constant:

```
#define SEPARATOR ':'
```

Then I call the split method

```
split(ords, input.c_str(), SEPARATOR);
```

And I get the following error:

> [C++ Error] File3.cpp(47): E2034 Cannot convert 'int' to 'const char *'

On the line, where I call the split method. Casting to const char* leads to the same result. Is there a bug in the IDE or am I just too dumb to see my own error in code?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us the *real* definition of `Orders::split`; copy-and-paste it, don't re-type it. The code you posted has the `sep` parameter declared as `const char`; I'll bet it's really `const char*`. And you name the parameter `sep`, but the code refers to `separator`. Details like this ***matter***.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`strtok` is looking for a `const char*` as delimiters. Try defining it like this instead:

```
#define SEPARATOR ":"
```

This is because you can specify a set of delimiters, so that `strtok` stops if *any* of those characters is found.